# error: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified for C

Tags: c, string, cs50

So I am trying to create a little joke with C and I don´t know what I am doing wrong. I see the Error "*error: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified*" and do not know how to fix it, can someone help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
int main(void){
    string a = get_string("ENTER YOUR NAME FOR READING\n");
    if (a == "david")
    ;
    {
        printf("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings are not first-class data types in C, so you have to do it with library calls.
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings

Comment: You are trying to compare the address of "david" with the address of a so it will evaluate to false

Comment: There is also a wild `;` there that makes it so that the `{ }` block is not a part of the `if` statement, remove it.

Comment: Using `cs50.h` should be the joke, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has three issues:

#### 1.

`if (a == "david")`

`a` decays to a pointer to the first element of array `a`.

`"david"` is a string literal.

With the `if` Statement, you attempt to compare the address of the array `a` by the address of the string literal `"david"`. String comparison dies not work that way in C.

Use `strcmp()` - header `string.h` to compare strings.

`strcmp()` returns 0 if the strings are equal. To make the `if` condition turn `true` you need to use `!` negation operator.

#### 2.

There is a misplaced `;` between the `if` condition and `if` body. Remove it.

#### 3.

The use of `cs50.h` is deprecated. If you are not required to use it explicitly, leave your hands off from it.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char a[20];

    printf("ENTER YOUR NAME FOR READING:\n");

    if (!fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin))
    {
         fputs("Failure at input", stderr);
         // further Error routine.
    }

    a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = 0;

    if (!strcmp(a,"david"))
    {
        printf("...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare two strings in c using a comparison operator.
Try using

```
strcmp(const char* one, const char* two)
```

That is, in your case
use

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
int main(void){
    char[] a = get_string("ENTER YOUR NAME FOR READING\n");
    char[] b = "david";
    if (!strcmp(a,"david"))
    {
        printf("...");
    }
}
```

Also, Strings in c are not declared as strings. They are declared as char arrays

Comment: I think you reversed the logic. In case of identity, strcmp returns 0, which is probably not what works inside an if as intended.

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Comment: `char[] b = "david";` is completely redundant in your code and confuses the questioner.

Comment: `char[] a = get_string("ENTER YOUR NAME FOR READING\n");` is an error. You should declare a pointer, not an array: `char *a = get_string("ENTER YOUR NAME FOR READING\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two char pointers like this `char *a, *b; a == b;` is accepted by the compiler, but if you are using such a syntax to compare the string values, then you may not get the results you are expecting. Some times it may evaluate to `true` or sometimes to `false`. The reason is, the program checks whether `a` and `b` are pointing to the same address, and not for if they have the same string value. Consider the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char* a = "test";

        char* b;

        if ((b="test") == a)
                printf("Impossible\n");
        else
                printf("Thought so\n"); 

        printf("%p %p\n", a, b);

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Impossible
0x55b6bd52d004 0x55b6bd52d004
```

As you see from the output, the `if` block is evaluated to `true`. The reason is also in the output; `a` and `b` are pointing to a similar address. Why?

> It comes from the *string-pooling*, one of the compiler optimization. Even though `a` and `b` are initialized at different points in the program, as they are referring to the same string constant, the string constant is initialized only once by the compiler.

Here is the `objdump` of the executable.

```
$ objdump -s -j .rodata 

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 74657374 00496d70 6f737369  ....test.Impossi
 2010 626c6500 54686f75 67687420 736f0025  ble.Thought so.%
 2020 70202570 0a00                        p %p..
```

`test` is initialized only once. For a quick check, consider this program's output and its `objdump` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char* a = "test";

        char* b;

        if ((b="test1") == a)
                printf("Impossible\n");
        else
                printf("Thought so\n"); 

        printf("%p %p\n", a, b);

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Thought so
0x557a96aa9004 0x557a96aa9009
```

`objdump`

```
$ objdump  -s -j .rodata a.out  

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 74657374 00746573 74310049  ....test.test1.I
 2010 6d706f73 7369626c 65005468 6f756768  mpossible.Though
 2020 7420736f 00257020 25700a00           t so.%p %p..
```

It is evident from the output that `a` and `b`are pointing to different locations, and both are having different string values that are initialized by the compiler separately. So, if `a` and `b` are having similar string values, does `a==b` always evaluate to true? Consider the below program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main()
{
        char* a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
        strcpy(a, "test");

        char* b;

        if ((b="test") == a)
                printf("Impossible\n");
        else
                printf("Thought so\n"); 

        printf("%p %p\n", a, b);

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Thought so
0x5607d9938260 0x5607d91fb004
```

Even though the `a` and `b` are having the same string values, `if` evaluate to `false`. Why?  The address `a` is pointing, which is created by `malloc()` belongs to the heap section of the executable, whereas the address `b` is pointing belongs to the data section of the executable, and they are indeed different.

So what should we do to compare the string values?

Well, it is straight forward, there are already library functions which can perform this task. You can use them with`string.h`. Consider the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main()
{
        char* a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
        strcpy(a, "test");

        char* b = "test";

        char* c;

        if (strcmp((c="test"), a) == 0)
                printf("Impossible\n");
        else
                printf("Thought so\n"); 

        if (strcmp(b, a) == 0)
                printf("Impossible\n");
        else
                printf("Thought so\n"); 

        if (strcmp(b, c) == 0)
                printf("Impossible\n");
        else
                printf("Thought so\n"); 

        printf("%p %p %p\n", a, b, c);

        return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Impossible
Impossible
Impossible
0x556debf41260 0x556deac28004 0x556deac28004
```

Irrespective of where `a`, `b` and `c` are pointing if they all are having the same string values, then `strcmp()` returns `0`.

Comment: @Mohith You should add it more in the context of the question and address what `"david"` actually is and why it returns an address.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I edited my answer, pls go through it. I hope all are happy now :)

Comment: "*... is accepted by the compiler, but if you are using such a syntax...*" - This suggests that comparing pointers would be a bad use in general, which is definitely not the case.

Comment: "*The address ``a`` is pointing, which is created by ``malloc()`` belongs to the heap section of the executable, whereas the address ``b`` is pointing belongs to the data section of the executable*" - The main difference is the different memory address. It has nothing to do with the heap or the stack itself. Also: You are losing focus.

Comment: I love when someone shows effort like you did but IMHO your answer loses the focus to the questioner´s issue. Your treat the topic if the condition is either evaluated to be `true` or `false` which does not cover the OP´s problem in particular. OP is asking for *why* s/he gets the error and how to solve it. Your answer is drifting away too much from these concerns.

Comment: Also: You changed the question itself too much to fit to your answer. That is not correct. It is not what the OP had asked for. - My advice: If you want to contribute your answer to the community, create this answer for the duplicate question, where it would be way more appropriate.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Thank you for all of your suggestions. Since I am new to the community, I am trying to learn how to write a proper answer, and your suggestions definitely helped.